# Proof $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ using Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$ be the complex Hilbert space that has $C[-\pi,\pi]$ as a linear subspace with inner product $(a,b)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi a(x)\overline{b(x)}dx$ for $a,b\in C[-\pi,\pi]$.
Further $\{e_n\}_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ where $e_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{inx}$ (for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$) is an orthonormal basis for $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$.
For $u(x)=x$ where $u\in L_2[-\pi,\pi]$, we find
$$(u,e_n)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi u(x)\overline{e_n(x)}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^\pi xe^{-inx}dx=\frac{2 i (π n\cos(π n)-\sin(π n))}{\sqrt{2\pi}n^2}.$$

> How do I use all the above to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}?$$

Edit: So by @G.Sassatelli's hint I find 
$$(u,e_n)=\frac{(-1)^n\sqrt{2\pi}i}{n}$$
and $$|(u,e_n)|^2=\frac{2\pi}{n^2}.$$
Then $||u||^2=\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^2dx=\frac{2\pi^3}{3}$. Then by Parseval we find 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2\pi}{n^2}=\frac{2\pi^3}{3}$$
which gives us our final result.

Comment: **Step 1)** Use heavy, obscure and convolute numerical methods ($\ddot\smile$) to estimate the values of $\cos(\pi n)$ and $\sin(\pi n)$. **Step 2)** Parseval's identity.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Do you mean by Parseval that $||u||^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |(u,e_n)|^2$?

Comment: Yes, that one.${}$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks, I did what you said and it came out nicely! :)

Comment: There is a different way of doing this where you use $v(x) = x^2$ rather than $u(x) = x$ which has the advantage that it is even and so only cosines appear. The reasoning is the same but it might be helpful for people (a somewhat unlikely bunch I admit) that do know integration but do not know about complex numbers: decomposing an real even function as sum of cosines can be carried out entirely in the 'real' world

Answer (score 1):

You should also take into account the case $n=0$, because $(u,e_n)$ is not defined for $n=0$. Also the integral is two times your result and this works because Parseval identity is: $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|(u,e_n)|^2 =2\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{n^2}+|(u,e_0)|^2+2\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = 4\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: Thanks for contributing. When you get more reputation, you can comment on posts. I think this would be best as a comment.

Comment: i tried to do that but I couldn't.. sorry..

Comment: Yes, I know you can't. That's why I said "when you get more reputation". Since you don't have enough reputation, a good approach would be to say what you did but expand it into a full answer, instead. Either way, thanks for taking the time to contribute.

Comment: You are right my integral is twice the value I want, why does it work out though? Also thanks for the input!

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it is more clear now! :)